# chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage is undefined in an extension page in an iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to access my extension's background page using `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage` function.

However, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage is not a function

I am calling the function from my `bar.js` file which is defined as a `web_accessible_resource` in my `manifest.json`

How do I make it work?

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "XPath Helper",
  "version": "1.0.13",
  "description": "Extract, edit, and evaluate XPath queries with ease.",
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "css": ["content.css"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["http://*/", "tabs", "identity", "identity.email"],
  "icons": {
    "32": "static/icon32.png",
    "48": "static/icon48.png",
    "128": "static/icon128.png"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "bar.css",
    "bar.html",
    "bar.js"
  ]
}
```

**bar.js** is a script inside `bar.html` (*not* a content script):

```
// ...

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
  // previosuly chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()
  chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(page){
    alert("hello");
  })  
})
```

**content.js**

```
// ...

  this.barFrame_ = document.createElement('iframe');
  this.barFrame_.src = chrome.extension.getURL('bar.html');

  document.body.appendChild(this.barFrame_);

// ...
```

Comment: Is it a content script, or are you injecting it into a page anyhow, or?..

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the chrome internal API is only available to JS files bundled with the extension.

Comment: calling it from my bar.js which is a web accessible resource. Attached my manifest.json

Comment: I suppose you inject `"bar.html"` into the page, correct? As an iframe? Can you add that code from `content.js`?

Comment: Also, just a side note, your permission pattern `"http://*/"` is probably incorrect, you should also use `"<all_urls>"` there.

Comment: Yes that is correct. bar.html creates an iframe and inserts it to the current page

Comment: Like I said, can you add the relevant code? "bar.html creates an iframe" doesn't make a lot of sense, did you mean "content.js"?

Comment: you cannot get the background page from a content script is likely your issue. only possible from popup.

Comment: try [chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getBackgroundPage)(callback)

Comment: @ZigMandel I'm actually not sure of the security context an injected extension iframe runs in. Sadly, didn't have time to test today - and I'm still waiting on injection code from OP.

Comment: @xan while i havent tried either, it wouldnt make sense for an injected script to get to getBackground page because it would break the single-threaded principle of javascript. each tab has its own thread thus it would allow to call a background function from more than one thread simultaneously which cant be. this is why background serializes access through messaging. the exception is the popup because there can be only one popup. just my theory.

Comment: @ZigMandel No, your theory is wrong. You can have 10 tabs opened with `chrome-extension://` pages from a same extension, and they can all use that function. It's usable as long as it's an "extension page". But an iframe in a regular webpage may be a lower security context, just because _in theory_ something cross-frame can happen.

Comment: hmm how does the extension background deal with threading? would making  a function call from the background object generate some sort of serialized call then? else how can an extension writer deal with multiple threads?

Comment: @ZigMandel I really don't know how it works under the hood, but probably with nasty blocking somewhere.

Comment: _\*sigh\*_ Again, what I really want to see is how you add `bar.html` to the page. I suppose that's in `content.js`. `bar.js` itself is not much interesting.

Comment: @pd176 Thanks for your last edit. I have trimmed down your question to what it _should_ have had as code, only relevant parts. I'll see if I can test it today.

Comment: I know this question is old and you may not have your solution source code available anymore, but it would be really helpful if you could add the message passing solution as an edit to your OP.

Comment: @DarrelHolt sorry man. I have no clue where that code is. Doubt it would even be valid now.

Comment: That's alright, I appreciate the response.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most extension APIs can *only* be used if the page runs in the extension process, i.e. the top-level frame is a non-[sandboxed](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/sandbox) `chrome-extension:` page.

`chrome-extension:`-frames in a non-extension process can only access the extension APIs available to [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and web pages. And unlike content scripts, they can also use web platform APIs at the extension's origin. For example, if you use `localStorage` in a content script, then the DOM storage of the page where the content script runs is accessed. If you use `localStorage` in a `chrome-extension:` page, then you'll get the extension's storage.

If you want to access functionality of the background page in your frame, use the [extension messaging APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to communicate between your frame and background page.

Comment: I _really_ wanted you to answer, as it would be most authoritative. Thank you.

Comment: Managed to get it working by message passing. Thanks everyone for your help! :)