# sending data between from content.js to popup.js in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, visual-web-developer

I would appreciate a minimal example showing how to send data (a string) from content.js to popup.js/html, in a chrome extension (I am using v3 manifest).

Starting with the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/messaging): it only talks about messaging between service worker (I am assume background.js) and content.js, not popup.js.
What I have tried:

1- The [broadcast](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/8hu2skfKrQ8) API, which did not do anything, no errors but at the same time nothing is being printed to the console or alerted, as if it was never called.

2- I tried listening to the messages directly from popup.js, I get an exception saying:  ["Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist" for Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76600328/error-could-not-establish-connection-receiving-end-does-not-exist-for-chrome), my take away was, you can not listen to sendMessage from popup.js but you have to do it from background.js

3- I tried using getBackgroundPage() as a few examples on the net suggested, but I ran into:
[getBackgroundPage() is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571111/chrome-extension-getbackgroundpage-is-undefined-in-an-extension-page-in-an-ifram) I found a few sources saying it is obsolete in V2 manifest, but I don't recall where did I read that.

my code setup right now.

```
//background.js 
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener
(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
            "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
            "from the extension");
    console.log("received data", request);
});


//content.js
(async () => {
    const response = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({Data:"Data"});
    })();

//popup.js
//not sure what to put here? I tried chrome.runtime.onMessage() but it never get triggered
```

In this setup background.js receives the data successfully, but I want to display it in popup.html/js eventually, if there is a way to send directly from content to popup I would like that, if not and I have to go through background.js then I don't mind, but I would appreciate a code working sample to understand how it all connect together.

Finally I would like to emphasize that I want to send from content.js to popup.js and not vice versa, I found multiple examples online that touches on sending from popup.js to content.js which is the opposite of I want to do.

Comment: The popup can receive messages via onMessage listener, but only when it's shown. There's no need for the background script. Instead you can send a request to the content script from the popup using chrome.tabs.sendMessage or use chrome.scripting.executeScript instead of messaging. What data are you sending?

Comment: @wOxxOm The data is nothing special, just parsing the html content of the current opened tab(which is why I need it to be in content.js) looking for a specific substring, if it exists, I just send it to the popup.js in which i display it in a fancy layout (that is the entire extension's job). I will look into executeScript, because I don't want the popup to be shown just to listen (because then I am not sure how to arrange it then such that it will work even with the user closes it, sounds like a bad idea to show it for listening purposes).